# How to declare # except line break for later usage?

Tags: uima, ruta

I use skip wild card `#` for text between rule elements.
However, I mark always per line, thus I m able to use `#{-CONTAINS(BREAK)}`
for example `RuleElementA #{-CONTAINS(BREAK)} RuleElementB` must be on a single line
How can I declare/save `#{-CONTAINS(BREAK)}` so that i could use later just shortcut like
`RuleElementA sc RuleElementB`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to annotate first your building block (i.e. Lines) and create your target annotations based on that (so-called Bottom-Up Matching Strategy in UIMA Ruta).

Therefore, your can annotate all the lines in the input document by following a naive approach:

```
DECLARE Line;
ADDRETAINTYPE(BREAK);
BREAK #{-> MARKONCE(Line)} @BREAK;
REMOVERETAINTYPE(BREAK);
```

This would allow you to remain on the line level while creating the target annotations. You could then iterate over all the `Line`s in the document in order to ensure the correctness of your span:

```
BLOCK (forEach) Line{CONTAINS(W)}{
    RuleElementA # RuleElementB
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could make use of the PlainTextAnnotator which is by default, part of the UIMA Ruta installation package. This approach can guarantee you a better line detection:

```
ENGINE utils.PlainTextAnnotator;
TYPESYSTEM Utils.PlainTextTypeSystem;

EXEC(PlainTextAnnotator, {Line, EmptyLine});
DECLARE FreeLine, LineFree;
ADDRETAINTYPE(WS);
EmptyLine Line{-> FreeLine};
Line{-> LineFree} BREAK[1,2] @EmptyLine;
Line{-> TRIM(WS)};
FreeLine{-> TRIM(WS)};
LineFree{-> TRIM(WS)};
REMOVERETAINTYPE(WS);
```